# jasmine library "no specs found" when running same test twice

Tags: node.js, jasmine-node

I want to be able to run the same test twice from a node express server, but noticed the second run of the same test always gives "no specs found".

Here is an example :
jasmine-test.js :

```
function jasmineExecute(fileName) {
    var jasmine = new Jasmine({});
    jasmine.onComplete(function(x) {
        if (x) {
            jasmineExecute("./test.js"); // risk of infinite loop
        }
        else {
            console.log('Test failed : ' + fileName);
        }
    });
    jasmine.execute([
        fileName
    ]);
}
jasmineExecute("./test.js");
```

test.js :

```
describe("We test that ", function() {
    it("The return should be true", function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

The result I have is as follow :

```
Randomized with seed 03122
Started
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 0.006 seconds
Randomized with seed 03122 (jasmine --random=true --seed=03122)
Randomized with seed 51883
Started


No specs found
Finished in 0.005 seconds
Incomplete: No specs found
Randomized with seed 51883 (jasmine --random=true --seed=51883)
Test failed : ./test.js
```

I am running on Jasmine 5.6.0 and node 8.9.4.
Any help on this will be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a known (though hard-to-find) issue with the jasmine package:

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/issues/30

The gist is that Jasmine [uses require()](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/blob/0f20d7e7fa3756c9bf4e6394e579c25594a84f15/lib/jasmine.js#L88) to load your spec files, and because Node.JS will only load a module once per "session", your spec files are not re-executed, so describe()/it() are not called.

If you have only a single spec file, you can fix this by removing the module from the cache using the [decache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decache) package:

```
const Jasmine = require("jasmine")
const decache = require("decache")

function jasmineExecute(fileName) {
    var jasmine = new Jasmine({});
    jasmine.onComplete(function(x) {
        if (x) {
            decache("./test.js")
            jasmineExecute("./test.js"); // risk of infinite loop
        }
        else {
            console.log('Test failed : ' + fileName);
        }
    });
    jasmine.execute([
        fileName
    ]);
}
jasmineExecute("./test.js");
```